Is there a way to capture the screen while electron app applies blur?
so I have been trying to develop a code in which I have an invisible electron app which functions with window blur, the person who is the owner of the computer can see anything on the computer but when he tries to take screenshots or video or try to show the app on the screen, the app isn't visible, I wanted to ask if there is a way to capture the APP directly because the 'APP Browser window blur' and the 'window blur' functions block me from showing others the app that is hidden on my screen only visible to me?
I tried many methods such as mss screening but failed, I thought maybe if I pull the images directly out of the GPU, it cannot be blurred since whatever the input to the computer is, the output should display what exactly is on the users screen
